# How do I increase the size of the main partition?

Tags: mac, macos, disk-utility

As indicated in the screenshot I can't increase the size of the main partition.

[image]

Comment: You can't unmount the disk you're booted from.

Comment: *You should edit your question/title so that they are congruent because it's unclear what you are asking.*  Your screenshot indicates you can't unmount the partition you booted from, not that you can't resize it.  To resize a partition, you need to boot from a different drive/partition.

Comment: yes , thank u , but how to unmount these

Comment: after that I want to increase (machintosh HD)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

1. Shut down the computer and reboot it while pressing  <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd>.
2. In the boot picker choose your recovery partition (name can vary, depending on your language settings).
3. In the recovery partition launch disc utility and perform the steps you tried already.

Comment: I can not log in to the recovery, when you click on the recovery waited a long time without result ٫Thank u for your efforts

Comment: Try to boot while holding down Cmd+R for recovery. Refer to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314 for more help.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but did,t show recovery

Comment: Try Cmd+Option+R for Internet recovery. There are some cases that a computer can run without a working recovery partition.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but did,t show recovery